# How can I clean up a whole column in a CSV by looking for a keyword and eliminating some delimiters?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

So I'm trying to clean up a .csv that our badging system exports. One of the issues with this export is that it doesn't separate the badging info (badge ID, activation state, company, etc.) into separate columns.

Here's what I need to do:

1. Create new .csv with only some of the columns
2. Rename top row
3. Clean up the CREDENTIALS column so it only outputs the activated badge number

**Problem:** I already did steps 1 and 2, however I need help going through the CREDENTIALS [3] column, to find the "Active" keyword and delete everything except for the first set of numbers. However, some credentials will have multiple badges separated by a |.

For instance, here is how the original .csv will looks like:

```
COMMAND,PERSONID,PARTITION,CREDENTIALS,EMAIL,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME
NoCommand,43,Master,{9065~9065~Company~Active~~~},personone@company.com,person,one
NoCommand,57,Master,{9482~9482~Company~Active~~~},persontwo@company.com,person,two
NoCommand,323,Master,{8045~8045~Company~Disabled~~~},personthree@company.com,person,three
NoCommand,84,Master,{8283~8283~Company~Disabled~~~|9861~9861~Company~Active~~~},personfour@company.com,person,four
NoCommand,46,Master,{9693~9693~Company~Lost~~~|9648~9648~Company~Active~~~},personfive@company.com,person,five
```

As you can see, the CREDENTIALS column [3] has a bunch of data included. It will also have multiple badge credentials separated by a |.

Here's what I have so far to complete steps 1 and 2:

```
import csv

# Empty data set that will eventually be written with the new sanitized data
data = []

# Keyword to search for
word = 'Active'

# Source .csv file that we will be working with
input_filename = '/path/to/original/csv'

# Output .csv file that we will create with the data from input_filename
output_filename = '/path/to/new/csv'

with open(input_filename, "rb") as the_file:
    reader = csv.reader(the_file, delimiter=",")
    next(reader, None)

    # Test sanitizing column 3
    for row in reader:
        for col in row[3]:
            if word in row[3]:
                print col

        new_row = [row[3], row[5], row[6], row[4]]

        data.append(new_row)


    with open(output_filename, "w+") as to_file:
        writer = csv.writer(to_file, delimiter=",")


        writer.writerow(['BadgeID', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'EmployeeEmail'])

        for new_row in data:
            writer.writerow(new_row)
```

So far the new .csv is looking like this:

```
    BadgeID,FirstName,LastName,EmployeeEmail
{9065~9065~Company~Active~~~},person,one,personone@company.com
{9482~9482~Company~Active~~~},person,two,persontwo@company.com
{8045~8045~Company~Disabled~~~},person,three,personthree@company.com
{8283~8283~Company~Disabled~~~|9861~9861~Company~Active~~~},person,four,personfour@company.com
{9693~9693~Company~Lost~~~|9648~9648~Company~Active~~~},person,five,personfive@company.com
```

I want it to look like this, with the "Active" credentials:

```
BadgeID,FirstName,LastName,EmployeeEmail
    9066,person,one,personone@company.com
    9482,person,two,persontwo@company.com
    8045,person,three,personthree@company.com
    8283,person,four,personfour@company.com
    9693,person,five,personfive@company.com
```

However, for my column 3 testing code block, I'm trying to at least make sure I'm grabbing the correct data. The weird thing is that when I print that column it comes out looking weird:

```
# Test sanitizing column 3
    for row in reader:
        for col in row[3]:
            if word in row[3]:
                print col
```

It outputs something like this:

```
C
a
r
d
s
~
A
c
t
i
v
e
~
~
~
}
{
8
8
2
4
~
8
8
2
4
~
```

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: `row` is a list of strings. `row[3]` is therefore a string. When you iterate over the elements in a string, you get characters. What is tripping you up?

Comment: Also, what is `word` in the `if` statement? It doesn't appear to be defined anywhere.

Comment: `row[3]` is the contents of the fourth column (a string), so when you do the `for col in row[3]:` each `col` is a single character of that string.

Comment: Ah! ok! So how do you iterate over each line in row[3]?

Comment: @MadPhysicist The variable was created in the beginning of the main script: word = 'Active'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by your output, you're grabbing the correct data!  The problem is: Column 3 is a string.  You're treating it like a list from the outset, resulting in characters being pulled from words.  Use string methods to get lists of words first.

Step by step with pseudo-code:

Strip those brackets

```
column3 = column3.strip("{}")
```

Since you might have multiple badges separated by "|", you should

```
badges_str = column3.split("|")
```

Now you have a list of strings, each representing a single badge.

```
badges = []
for badge in badges_str:
    badges.append(badge.split("~"))
```

Now you have a list of individual badge listings that you can use indexes on.

```
for badge in badges:
    # test for the Active badges, then do things
    if badge[3] == "Active":
        do_something(badge[0])
        do_something_else(badge[1])
        etc...
```

That doesn't give you actual code, but should get you to the next steps to get there.

Comment: Thank you! This got me in the right track in figuring everything out!!!